# C# - Is there a way to load classes from a namespace without reflection

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

the question's title may seem unclear since I haven't added any context.

**THE CONTEXT:**

So I'm making a terminal system (with basic commands such as 'chdir' or 'rd'), and I was trying to figure out if there is a sort of way to basically to add that command to a list so I can actually use it via my terminal without reflection meaning that I'm not actually trying to find that classes inside a namespace and then call a function to add it into the list.

So my first approach was to manually call a function for each command, but it was kind of a mess. So I tried to use reflection with the code below:

```cs
        public static void RegisterCommands()
        {
            Type[] terminalCommands = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(ns => ns.Namespace == "Server.Cli.Commands").ToArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < terminalCommands.Length; i++)
            {
                MethodInfo? register = terminalCommands[i].GetMethod("Register", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
                if (register == null)
                    continue;

                register.Invoke(null, null);
            }

            Initialized = true;
        }
```

At first, it seems to be a good approach but this app focuses on performances.

Is there a solution to my problem? Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: "but this app focuses on performances" You seem to be *implying* that doing it this way negatively affects your performance. Did you actually try it? Did you measure anything? If not, how do you know a "problem" even exists?

Comment: @Sweeper Reflection is known to cost in performance. Although I asked for an alternative, **nothing else**  I will surely determinate that later on, sure it's currently not a problem, but it can be in the future.

Comment: What's the problem with just calling `ChdirCmd.Register(); RdCmd.Register(); // etc...` during startup? You'd have to add a call there for every new command of course.

Comment: @Good Night Nerd Pride Yeah, and that's the thing, I prefer to make things so I don't have to worry about later on, that's basically why I changed and it's a bit more convenient.

Comment: I tried around a bit with a register interface and static ctors but the bottom line is you can't get around listing all your commands somewhere manually. Would be same with dependency injection. If you want that automagic, you'd have to use reflection AFAIK.

Comment: What if you use "command pattern" ? Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: @RivoR. It sounds similar to what I did. Although it still requires to call the function directly which is something I want to avoid since I haven't talk about it but I have that function that to check which command should be called. And all of the system I made pretty much use reflection.

Comment: I am afraid you can't do it without reflection. Here is another idea : what if each command is an executable process, meaning you build each command for your terminal system as an EXE file that you load from the disc and start programmatically when any text command is validated. This way, no reflection needed. However you'll have a lot of EXE files to manage. I guess that is how some of the MS-DOS commands are built. Your application might need to be redesigned if you choose that way.

Comment: @RivoR. Yeah that's right, but I think I will stay with what I've done it's probably the best way for my case right now; but thanks for ideas I appreciate!